# Creating a Query with combination of "CASE WHEN" and "GROUP BY"

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case-when

i try to create a table, where i create columns with CASE WHEN, which should be grouped by Candidates. I tried it already many times and searched in forum but i don't get the solution.

```
SELECT History.ApplicantId
       ,MAX(Interested)
       from (
       SELECT  History.ApplicantId
               ,CASE WHEN (ActivityId = 88) THEN 1 END AS Interested
From History) a
GROUP BY History.ApplicantId
```

So my result should be two columns. The first one is the applicant and the second if he was interested. 1 or NULL.

But i get 'The multi-part identifier "History.ApplicantId" could not be bound'.

What should i do?

Best regards

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The query makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just aggregate in a single level query:

```
SELECT
    ApplicantId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityId = 88 THEN 1 END) AS Interested
FROM History
GROUP BY ApplicantId;
```

This would report `1` should the applicant be interested, and `NULL` otherwise.

Comment: Hey thats much easier. Thank you really much. :)